# Cannot find symbol: Databinding component

Tags: android, data-binding

```
ext.globalCompileSdkVersion = 28

ext.globalBuildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"

ext.globalTargetSdkVersion = 26

ext.globalMinimumSdkVersion = 21

ext.globalAndroidSupportLibVersion = "27.1.1"

ext.globalGooglePlayServiceVersion = "11.2.0"
```

Using these versions along with `android.databinding.enableV2=true` still no luck.

Created different modules and using databinding in both of them

Answer (score 0):

```
dataBinding {
    enabled true
}
```

add this code in build.gradle(Module:app) file